# Why Unity Visual Studio doesn't recognise "Using MlAgents" when I create a new project, but recognises it within the demo project?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, ml-agent

I've been trying to get Unity's MLAgents installed on my system.
After going through the detailed guide "https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Installation-Windows.md" I managed to get the demo projects like the "3D Ball" to work and train successfully.

My problem is that when I create a new project I get an error highlighted when I include "Using MlAgents" which states "The type of namespace name 'mlagents' could not be found".

I don't have much experience with Unity, so I'm expecting this to be a silly thing I've missed, for instance you might have to import the package, but I have no clue how?

All the tutorials I've found are really outdated so this is my last resort. Any help or advice is appreciated.

I don't understand how the demo project has no errors with "Using mlagents" but new projects do.

Comment: because MLagents is not by default available for VS, you to add it in your project.

Answer (score 2):

You must include the ML-Agents folder from the UnitySDK in your new project.

Follow the steps from the [Environment Setup](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Installation.md#environment-setup) to install ML Agents on your computer.
Then navigate to ml-agents/UnitySDK/Assets/ and copy the ML-Agents folder. Place this folder in your new project's Assets folder.

You should now be able to import MLAgents in your scripts.